# Keeping table cells consistent width when data missing

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a dynamic page displaying groups of tables all with different data. I have defined the widths of data cells using percents. My problem is that some columns donot display data, which means not all tables display at the same width. Aesthetically it looks bad and I'd like to keep them all the same width. Is there a way I can do this in css and not have to use pixels for widths? Here is my current css:

```css
table.motionEventsTable {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:90%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
table.motionEventsTable td:nth-child(1){width:18%;} /* first column */ 
table.motionEventsTable td:nth-child(2){width:15%;} /* second column */ 
table.motionEventsTable td:nth-child(3){max-width:15%; word-wrap:break-word;} /* third column */ 
table.motionEventsTable td:nth-child(4){width:22%;} /* fourth column  */ 
table.motionEventsTable td:nth-child(5){width:30%;} /* fifth column */
```

```html
<table id="motionsTable" summary="This table is an index of all papers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!--<th>&nbsp;</th> -->
      <th scope="col">Task </th>
      <th scope="col">Event</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">person</th>
      <th scope="col">result</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>lkdjf dpfj dlkfkhg pldfjk;l</td>
      <td>ojkdfh dsfkjh</td>
      <td>August 29, 2013</td>
      <td>
        August 29, 2013 jlkfdj</td>
      <td>James Bradley gfhf;lmk fglkjm ;ldf;ljgk ;dlfjkgd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fgh</td>
      <td>fghfg</td>
      <td>August 29, 20136 787899 990 000</td>
      <td>
        August 29, 2013
        &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>James Bradley</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fghgfn</td>
      <td>fghfg</td>
      <td>August 29, 2013</td>
      <td>
        August 29, 2013
        &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>James Bradley</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>August 29, 2013</td>
      <td>fghfg</td>
      <td>August 22, 2013</td>
      <td>
        James Bradley
      </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>fghfgh</td>
      <td>gfhfh</td>
      <td>August 29, 2013</td>
      <td>
        James Bradley
      </td>
      <td>n/a</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, simply using `table-layout: fixed;` in your table's CSS will do exactly what you require.

This snaps all columns to the same width, unless you specify a specific width for certain columns, in which case the remaining space is distributed evenly between non-specified columns.

Comment: I don't know how I couldn't find this. I searched google but didn't see anything regarding table-layout property that fix my problem. It works thanks.

Comment: Sometimes the hardest part is figuring out _how_ to google something. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a table property for that: `table-layout`, if you use it with the value **fixed**: `table-layout:fixed;` in your CSS it will give you the same width for every column.

**Check how it works here:** [CSS table-layout Try It Yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_table-layout&preval=fixed)